# Difficulty with MySQL Inner Join range query

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm really struggling with a MySQL query that I'm really hoping someone can help me with. I have three tables in a MySQL database - Table A, B, and C. I would like to find all values from Table A, column 1 (a.1) that match a value in Table B column 2 (b.2). Then for each b.2 match, find all other b.2 values in Table B that are within a range of +/- 100 of the integer value found in b.3 within rows where a.1 matched b.2. Then finally I need to take these b.2 values and find matching b.2 values in Table C column 4.

Here is how I was trying to perform the query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM TableB AS b 
INNER JOIN TableA AS a ON b.2 = a.1 
AND b.3 >= (b.3 - 100) 
AND b.3 <= (b.3 + 100) 
INNER JOIN TableC as c 
ON b.2 = c.4;
```

I've tried to illustrate what I am trying to do with a picture, I hope this helps.
[image]

Comment: What is the problem? The query seems to represent what you are stating. Are you having performance problems in the b-bb join? Otherwise, it seems OK. And by the way, I normally find range comparissons easier to read with the intermediate value in the middle, something like small_value <= intermediate_value AND intermediate_value <= large_value (but that is a detail)

Comment: Should the 'WHERE' not be 'ON'?

Comment: It should be `on` not `where` when you are joining TableA

Comment: My query works but it only return results from the first inner join. For some reason the range query does not seem to work?

Comment: Your query should produce only a syntax error.

Comment: @ypercube I've fixed the example to reflect the my actual query.

Comment: OK but now, your query does not have a self-join on `B` table. Have you tried @MJB's or @Erwin's answer?

Comment: To your updated question: AND `b.3 >= (b.3 - 100)` is always true (and therefore nonsensical). You are missing one step in your query. My first answer should still be correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your description I distilled this query:

```
SELECT a.one, b.three, c.four
FROM   a
JOIN   b AS b0 ON b0.two = a.one             -- intermediary step
JOIN   b ON b.three BETWEEN b0.three - 100 
                        AND b0.three + 100   -- real b values
JOIN   c ON c.four = b.two
```

#### Issues I see in your query:

- You have `WHERE a.1 = b.2` where it should be `ON a.1 = b.2`
- In the final JOIN you have `ON bb.3 = c.4`, while according to your description it must be ON `bb.2 = c.4`.
- If your **description is wrong** and your **demo is right**, then we can simplify to:

```
SELECT a.one, b.three, c.four
FROM   a
JOIN   b ON b.two = a.one
JOIN   c ON c.four BETWEEN b.three - 100 AND b.three + 100
```

Comment: @ypercube: query is correct as it is. No additional alias needed. But getting rid of horiz. ruler is welcome.

Comment: it is needed because you have `JOIN   c ON c.four = b2.two` in the last join. You are using a `b2`. But I won't mess any more with your query.

Comment: @ypercube: I only feature `a.one, b.three, c.four` in the SELECT, because `b.two` is identical with `c.four` and `b0.two` is identical with `a.one` anyway.

Comment: Yeah, OK, that is a minor issue anyway. The OP may want other data to be shown anyway. Just thought that it would be good (for debugging) to have both `b0.three` and `b.three` shown.

Comment: @ypercube: I see, that would make sense. But really incidental here.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter Thank you! this did precisely what I was looking for, I very much appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1):

Before answering, we'd need to know what is happening. Does it work? What does it produce? Is there an error?

Anyway, here is my guess (also, I am assuming you don't use column names like 1 or 2 or 3, and that is just for demo purposes):

```
SELECT *
FROM TableB AS b
  INNER JOIN TableA AS a
    ON a.1 = b.2
  INNER JOIN TableB as bb
    ON bb.3 between (b.3 - 100) AND (b.3 + 100)
  INNER JOIN TableC as c
    ON bb.3 = c.4
```

The only change is on the join condition for table A. Yours should have been a syntax error. And I simplified the between condition.

Comment: Your query copies the mistake of the OP: ON `bb.3 = c.4`. If this was correct, you could omit the second JOIN on `TableB` and JOIN `TableC` directly. However, according to the OP's description (and now diagram, too), it should really be ON `bb.2 = c.4` in the final JOIN.

Comment: Yeah, I admit I did not go into this too deeply. I could not understand what was going wrong initially, and I responded in a way that I hoped would elicit more info from OP. Thanks for correcting me though -- I appreciate it.